# Parameters get null in controller after url rewrite ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url-rewriting

I have problems since I've tried to rewrite my URLs.

With the default route everything is ok. 
I have an ActionLink in the view, which sends some parameters to the controller.

```
@{string selectedCar = "";
if (Request.Cookies["url"] != null)
{
  selectedCar = Request.Cookies["url"] == null ? string.Empty : Request.Cookies["url"].Values["url"].ToString();
}
string regExp = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]";
string productName = Regex.Replace(@c.Name, regExp, "-");
string productCode = @c.Code.Trim();
<p class="text-center text-muted">

  <a href="@Url.Action("ProductDetails", "Product" , new { category = productName, selected = selectedCar, code = productCode})" id="link">
        Details
   </a>
```

If I use the default route, which is defined in the Routing.config, all the parameters are correctly set. But if I try to use the route defined by me for the Details page, the parameters are not set correctly. The category and the code parameter are nulls.

This is my Route config:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Categories",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{selected}/{category}/{engineId}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "SubCategories"
           , selected = UrlParameter.Optional,
             category = UrlParameter.Optional,
             engineId = UrlParameter.Optional
           }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Details",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{category}/{selected}/{code}‌​",
           defaults: new
           {
               controller = "Product",
               action = "ProductDetails",
               category = UrlParameter.Optional,
               selected = UrlParameter.Optional,
               code = UrlParameter.Optional
           });


        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Purchase",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}‌​",
          defaults: new { controller = "Purchase", action = "PurchaseProduct", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );



        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

[image]

I've tried to resolve, but without any luck. The problem is in the route, but since I don't have too much experience with routing, I didn't figure it out what can be the problem. Can you please advise? Thanks!

Comment: All your routes are essentially identical and your link matches the first one. You need to make your routes specific - e.g. the first one should be `url: "Product/SubCategories/{id}/{selected}/{category}/{engineId}",` and the 2nd `url: "Product/ProductDetails/{category}/{selected}/{code}‌​",` etc

Comment: And only the last parameter can be marked `UrlParameter.Optional`, but since you seem to be wanting to provide them all, then just remove them.

Comment: It seems that this solution resolved my problem, but now the controller method ProductDetails is called 2 times, first it gets the correct parameters, but second time the parameter name = Scripts and the selected = "jquery-1.8.2.min.js". The Details page is loaded, but in the background I get some exceptions because of these incorrect values. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I assume you have other code making a 2nd call which you have not shown us.